# iOS Charts - Setting border and border colour for chart's components

Tags: ios, ios-charts

is there any way to set a **border** and a **border colour** for graphs parts? All I have managed to find so far was a border around the graph's view.

1. Around each chart's component/row - the top red circle
2. Around the highlighted part of the chart's component/row - the second/middle red circle

**Goal**

[image: Goal]

**Current State**

[image]

Comment: I guess you have to rewrite the renderer, and file a feature request on github